# Regex match fails when adding special characters

Tags: php, regex

Consider this,

```
$uri = '/post/search/foo';

$pattern = '~/post/search/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+(?=/|$)~i';

$matches = array();

preg_match($pattern, $uri, $matches);

print_r($matches); // Success
```

It works fine, since `[A-Za-z0-9_-]` belongs to `foo`. Since I'm writing a route plugin, 
I want this to be abble to match special chars as well.

I imagine a regex pattern to be like this:

`[A-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+|\/?><~"№;:'*]+(?=/|$)`

**I've tried** to escape each special character with a slash, and escape a whole pattern using `preg_quote()` with no luck - I always encounter compilation failures.

The **question** is, how a proper matching for `A-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+|\/?><~"№;:'*` should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't want to just use an ungreedy `.`?

As in:

```
'~/post/search/.+(?=/|$)~iU'
```

Comment: But, wouldn't the `.+` part always match until `$`? Wouldn't skip all slashes between them?

Comment: @Birei If there is a slash, the ungreediness ("U" flag) would end the `.+` match

Comment: Sorry then. I was not aware of that option. I thought it was done with `.+?` like in most of other languages.

Answer (score 2):

Escaping inside the character class is not difficult, only `^` (only at the first position), `-` (not at the first or last position), `\` and `[]` are special characters there, and `'` as string delimiter. And additionaly the regex delimiter.

You use `~` as regex delimiter and I think this is the critical point in your character class, because the delimiter is not escaped  by default when using `preg_quote()`.

So this should be working

```
[A-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+|\/?><\~"№;:\'*]+(?=/|$)
```